# Keycloak booting-time exception on Windows 10

Tags: java, wildfly, keycloak, infinispan

I've downloaded v11.0.2 on https://www.keycloak.org/downloads as .zip . Extracted the files and run the /bin/standalone.bat . But it gives me [this](https://pastebin.pl/view/ddbeb7ef) error. I looked at [Keycloak's guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/index.html). I've read so many guides about this none of them got stuck there.

Comment: Are you changing the config for Infinispan?

Comment: No, i didn't change anything. And I haven't used İnfinispan before so there should be no old configs

Comment: If you are tired trying to install keycloak locally then can you try installing it in Docker it is super easy that way

Comment: @TusharJajodia I ended up running docker container as you recommended. The only negative side is that my os is windows so it uses extra resource to run docker top of windows.

Comment: Yes Docker will take up extra resources but you can add other application in it with very less overhead